# Can I create a Twitter account with a URL?

Tags: twitter

Can I create a Twitter account with a URL?

Something like this: http://twitter.com/signup?name=NAME&pass=PASS&username=USER .

Comment: The Twitter API does not support creating accounts, so it is not possible to create accounts programatically. See: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Common) websites do not allow registration via [GET](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) request.

The are several reasons but the main are security and mass registration avoidance (easier with `POST` registration):

> GET requests can be cached
>
> GET requests remain in the browser history

See more in the link I posted.

Comment: Sooooooooooooooo.... I can't?

Comment: No, you can't really.

Comment: You welcome, some websites declare in their terms and conditions you may register an account only in the dedicated form.